# Modify properties when class is created

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a lot of controllers that extract the same values from the input value `stdo`, as seen in the controller below.

```
// Controller
public ActionResult GetValues(StatisticsDTO stdo)
{
    var startDate = DateTime.Parse(stdo.Timespan.Substring(0, 10));
    var endDate = DateTime.Parse(stdo.Timespan.Substring(12));

    // Rest of controller actions ...
}
```

What I would like to do is have these two actions done in the constructor of the `StatisticsDTO` object, and then added to another property.

I've tried moving the rows into two different constructors but the `TimeSpan`
 value is always null. Is this possible at or is there some other way to refactor this?

```
public class StatisticsDTO
{
    public string Timespan { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } // New property
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; } // New property

    public StatisticsDTO() {
        this.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(0, 10));
        this.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(12));
    }

    public StatisticsDTO(string Timespan, string Country, string AppName)
    {
        this.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(0, 10));
        this.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(12));
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I'm after here.

**EDIT**
Assume I'm calling this action with a `$ajax` call from the client with the data variable

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "/GetValues",
    data: { Timespan: "01/01/01 - 02/02/02", Country: "US", AppName: "V1" }
});
```

These parameters are translated into a `StatisticsDTO` object. I'd like the `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties be set in the constructor when the stdo object is created.

Comment: What do you mean: "added to another property"? What property?

Comment: When is your property named `Timespan` set?

Comment: Can the `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties be read only?  If so, you can do the parsing when someone accesses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default (i.e. parameterless) constructor here couldn't work as it runs before you have any value assigned to your `Timespan` property. Remove it and the other constructor should work fine.

However, you appear to be using this object as an MVC parameter, so having no parameterless constructor won't work. You could do this:

```
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(0, 10)); }
}

public DateTime EndDate
{
    get { return DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(12)); }
}
```

Alternatively, if you intend to modify the start/end date properties later on, you could do this:

```
private string _timespan;
public string Timespan 
{
    get { return _timespan; }
    set
    {
        _timespan = value;
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(0, 10));
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse(Timespan.Substring(12));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! This is what I'm after, and the first example is good enough for me. The problem with my code was that the second constructor was never hit, only the first, empty one.